# Cannot update Request timeout in Application Gateway HTTP settings

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We are trying to update the `Request timeout` in the HTTP settings of our Azure Application Gateway. When trying to save we get the following error:

> Application Gateway does not have enough capacity. Required capacity
>   is atleast 200, currently available capacity in subnet is 11

We are puzzled as to why this error appears when updating the `Request timeout` field. There is no reason for the required capacity to be `200` and it seems unrelated to the `Request timeout` setting.

To resolve or get around this we tried several things:

1. **Expanding the subnet range**. (Failed, subnet in use, even with stopped gateway)
2. **Update the property with powershell** (Failed, setting does not stick, no error)
3. **Create a new subnet**, stop the gateway, set the subnet for the gateway using powershell. (Failed, subnet switch not sticking for unknown reason and no error)

Comment: It seems there is a known bug. We are in touch with Microsoft at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just in touch with Microsoft and we had the same error message while changing any setting in the AppGW. The error was to small subnet (/28) and a workaround was to change scaling from autoscale to manual under the Properties blade.